# How to get c++ enum value in Xcode?

Tags: xcode, enums, lldb

I would like to know if this is possible to get the value of c++ enum item in Xcode.

In Visual Studio you just have to hover the item and you got a tooltip with its value but it does not do the same in Xcode.

I also tried to print the value in lldb console without success.

For instance with this simple enum:

```
enum Params{
    eP1,
    eP2,
    eP3,
    eP4,
    eP5,
};
```

I tried different ways like `p eP1` or  `p Param::eP1`.

I also tried with an `enum class` with the same result.

Answer (score 2):

At present, you have to use enumName:enumElement, but that is working for me:

```
 > cat foo.cpp
#include <stdio.h>

enum Params
  {
    eP1,
    eP2,
    eP3,
    eP4
  };

int main()
{
  enum Params elem = eP1;
  printf ("%d\n", elem);
  return 0;
}
 > lldb a.out
(lldb) target create "a.out"
Current executable set to 'a.out' (x86_64).
(lldb) b s -p printf
Breakpoint 1: where = a.out`main + 29 at foo.cpp:14, address = 0x0000000100000f6d
(lldb) run
Process 26752 launched: '/private/tmp/a.out' (x86_64)
Process 26752 stopped
* thread #1, queue = 'com.apple.main-thread', stop reason = breakpoint 1.1
    frame #0: 0x0000000100000f6d a.out`main at foo.cpp:14
   11   int main()
   12   {
   13     enum Params elem = eP1;
-> 14     printf ("%d\n", elem);
                          ^
   15     return 0;
   16   }
Target 0: (a.out) stopped.
(lldb) expr Params::eP1
(int) $0 = 0
```

If you still can't get this to work, can you post a more complete example where it fails?

The problem for lldb, BTW, is that the debug information is organized into the full debug information  and then a name->info accelerator table.  lldb depends on the accelerator tables for lookup (otherwise it would have to go looking through all the debug info which can get pretty slow for big apps).  The accelerator tables at present only have the name of the enum, not the element names.

Comment: thank you for your answer. After comparing your example with mine, it seems that you need to have instantiated an element of the enum in the scope to make it work.

Comment: Yes, that is expected behavior.  Some compilers (for sure gcc & clang) - in an effort to reduce debug info size - won't emit debug information for "unused types".  In most "real" apps this isn't a problem: you don't generally have that many types lying around that nobody uses.  But when you are experimenting with something in a little toy program you often have to do a little extra work to ensure the type is considered "used".